# Terraform Create Route53 record for each aws_instance crreated

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-route53, terraform-provider-aws

I have written the following Terraform code:

```
resource "aws_instance" "agents" {
  count = 100
  key_name = var.Jenkins_Controller_KeyName

  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  ami = data.aws_ami.latest-amazonlinux2.id
}
```

My goal is to create 100 Jenkins agent EC2 instances. I would like to create Route53 records for each one. So if I have `count = 100`, it would create 100 A records like this (in pseudo code):

```
for i in 0..100
   create_a_name("worker" + i.to_string)
```

How can I do this in Terraform? Is it possible?

Comment: in the same way you have the `count=100` on the `aws_instance` put that count on the reoute 53 record. The target of the record should then be `aws_instance.slaves[count.index].something`

Comment: [Jenkins uses the terms controller and agents](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-agents/) rather than master and slaves (and has AFAIK never used the term slaves) so I've updated that terminology to make it easier for people using the correct terminology to find this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `count` it may be better to use [aws_autoscaling_group](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/autoscaling_group) with `desired_capacity` and `max_size` of 100. This way ensures **high-availability and fault tolerance** your slave instances. A something to consider perhaps.

But anyway, to answer your question regarding `aws_route53_record`. You can do something along these lines:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "www" {
 
  count = length(aws_instance.agents)
 
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.primary.zone_id
  name    = "worker${count.index}.example.com"
  type    = "A"
  ttl     = "300"

  # not clear from your question if you want to use public or private ip?
  records = [aws_instance.agents[count.index].public_ip]
}
```

Comment: it seems there is a missing closing square bracket in the `records`. :)

Comment: @MarkoE Thanks for spotting that. I just fixed that.

Comment: Kind of wondering why records is an array. Why would you ever need more than one?

Comment: @RyanGlen You can return multiple IPs for redundancy purposes or load balancing. So client can try first IP, if it does not work, then try second-spare one.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that worked that way lol.